# How to change the format of column of strings of a MySQL table for a subset of the rows?

Tags: mysql

Specifically, for the values returned by the following query:

```
select foo from mytable where foo rlike '^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$';
```

I want to update to the format `123:foo;`

How should I accomplish this?

Comment: Will there **always** be a semicolon at the end?  Also, it's unclear why you use a regexp with numbers only, but your specified "target" format mixes numbers and letters.

Comment: The target contains the text that was matched, the original value. Yes, the new format has a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET foo=CONCAT('123:',foo,';') WHERE foo RLIKE '^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$';
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('123:',foo,';') 
FROM mytable 
WHERE foo 
  rlike '^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$';
```

Have fun.

**EDIT**

you can attach as many params to CONCAT as you want.

Comment: Thanks! There's also a trailing semicolon though. Also, what about the actual update to the database?